# near jump changed to Short jump automatically

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, tasm, short

I need near jump(E9 XX XX) and specify that in code, but TASM (and MASM) changed that to Short(EB XX NOP) after assemble.

```
MAIN SEGMENT BYTE

ASSUME CS:MAIN,DS:MAIN,SS:NOTHING

ORG 100H


HOST:

jmp NEAR PTR VIRUS_START 

db ’VI’

mov ah,4CH

mov al,0

int 21H ;terminate normally with DOS

COMFILE DB ’*.COM’,0 ;search string for a com file
VIRUS_START:
```

Comment: Why does it matter? And are you trying to get *us* to help you make your virus work??

Comment: I need this for educational purpose, please help if you know, thanks

Comment: I have always been happy when the assembler fixed my jumps and have never tried to make it not do that.

Comment: thank you for reply, but in this sample i don't need assembler optimization, i need a way to disable that

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to enforce the use of the *near* jump instead of the *short* jump is having enough bytes to jump over!

- Either use some padding like:

  ```
  COMFILE DB ’*.COM’,0 ;search string for a com file
  padding db 127 dup (0)
  VIRUS_START:
  ```
- or else add some useful subroutine(s) before the label *VIRUS_START*

A further possibility is to encode the jump manually.
Just write `db 0E9h, 14, 0`

Answer (score 3):

You can work around your assembler by manually encoding a `jmp near rel16`:

```
db  0E9h                    ;  JMP NEAR opcode
dw  VIRUS_START-$-2         ;  relative address
```

$ is the absolute address of current instruction (dw). 
($+2) address of next instruction (after our jmp).

(VIRUS_START - ($+2)) - difference between target address (VIRUS_START) and next instruction. It will be added to IP register during execution JMP instruction.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer for MASM or TASM, but perhaps this will be useful to someone:

In NASM, `jmp near VIRUS_START` does enforce the long encoding.  You can also use stuff like `add dx, strict word 1` to force the imm16 encoding instead of the imm8.  See http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.7

```
; ASSUME: I think there's a way to port that to NASM, but IDK how.
ORG 100H

HOST:
jmp NEAR VIRUS_START   ; with override
jmp VIRUS_START        ; without
... ; your code unmodified
VIRUS_START:
```

assemble with `nasm -fbin foo.asm`.  Then see what we got with `ndisasm -o 0x100 foo` (which only knows about flat binaries):

```
00000100  E91000            jmp 0x113
00000103  EB0E              jmp short 0x113
```